# Redis and twemproxy

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, twemproxy

I have initially formed a Redis cluster with 3 masters and 3 slaves in my local machine.

Now I want to use [twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy) on Redis cluster so I have used, the below lines(see below) as my config file and implemented twemproxy with Redis cluster.

But the problem I am facing is, out of 100 keys I have sent to `port 22122` only 30-40 are been registered in the Redis cluster.

Please help!

```
beta:
  listen: **.**.**.***:22122
  hash: fnv1a_64
  hash_tag: "{}"
  distribution: ketama
  auto_eject_hosts: false
  timeout: 400
  redis: true
  servers:
   - **.**.**.***:8006:3 server1
   - **.**.**.***:8007:2 server2
   - **.**.**.***:8008:1 server3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Twemproxy and Redis Cluster together because they both try to shed keys across a cluster. Pick one and use just that one.

That said this isn't a stackexchange question because it is about administration. Try any further related questions on serverfault.